# ReactJS, Express application self hosting on internal dedicated IP server

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs, server, self-hosting

I know we can host our ReactJS application on Amazon, Microsoft Azure, Heroku etc.
But what are the important steps and security precautions required to do in order to setup on an internal hosting server.

1. What are pros and corn of having **Linux** or **Windows** based server. (also which versions are relevant)
2. How to setup an SSL on local hosting server. What are options.
3. What are the security precautions to be made.
4. An internet line with dedicated IP from ISP can be connected, but do need to have any security hardware in middle in the network?
5. How to setup/connect a purchased domain name (www.mydomain.com) to an internal hosting server.
6. How to have multiple IPs to an internal hosting server, so if one server fails or one network fails the other keeps working with the purchased domain name.
7. How to log IP(visitors) access log in hardware level to keep server secure.
8. How to setup internal code version control system (using any local version control system and also GitHub), so if one deployment fails or creates any trouble; we can then restore to older code version.
9. How to setup a mailing server to send and receive emails and also how can we setup different emails on local hosting server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a look at the following link which contains most of the details related to most common server setup practice. Hopefully this will answer the question related to the server environment setup.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/5-common-server-setups-for-your-web-application

In the *Related Articles* Section (at end of the above article) there are lots of information on setting on NodeJS appliction on Ubunto etc. Hopefully the discussion there will clarify the concepts in more depth. e.g. [How To Deploy a Node.js and MongoDB Application with Rancher on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-and-mongodb-application-with-rancher-on-ubuntu-16-04)